# conectarse a una BD sql server seleccionada en tiempo de ejecucion

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

tengo una app web, que necesita conectarse a una bd sql server. Esto lo logra a traves de la tipica definicion determinada en conecctionstring en app.config.
necesito poder tener una lista de connectionstrmgs (definiciones) a fin de poder pasar de una a otra al momento de la conexion a la bd. esto en tiempo de ejecucion. algo asi como un listado de bases de datos (servers) entre los cuales elegir en un momento determinado.
Se puede hacer esto?

Comment: Lo has intentado?

Comment: ?? que pasa viejo?? porque ese comentario? si estoy preguntando esto aca, es para saber si me pueden orientar en como hacer esto.. no para que me des la solucion..  no veo que tu "lo haz intentado" sea muy amable de tu parte

Comment: Te pregunta si lo has intentado porque no hay un problema concreto. Si lo hubieras intentado, la pregunta sería algo asi como "estoy intentando esto y me aparece este error o el resultado no es el esperado". Con frecuencia, este tipo de problemas vienen acompañadas de un __[mcve]__ que lo ilustra. Si quieres editar esta pregunta, sigue esta guía: __[ask]__.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo en el `App.config` de la siguiente manera:

En vez de poner la propiedad como `Connection String`, lo dejas como `String` y vas separando todas las conexiones con algún separador, por ejemplo `'#'`, debe ser un separador que no exista en las conexiones, así que tu mismo puedes elegir cuál.

Entonces lo dejaríamos de la siguiente forma:

`Data Source=Server1;Initial Catalog=DataBase1;User id=User1;Password=Pass1;#Data Source=Server2;Initial Catalog=DataBase2;User id=User2;Password=Pass2;#Data Source=Server3;Initial Catalog=DataBase3;User id=User3;Password=Pass3;...`

Entonces cuando inicies la aplicación haces un `Split` de esta `String` y te devolverá una lista (string[]) de cadenas de conexión:

```
VariableAppConfigConexiones.Split('#')
```

Comment: gracias por la idea..  voy a ir viendo como implementarla. saludos!